# Google Bigquery java client listTables return numBytes and numRows as null

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-java-client

When I try to find the size of all the tables using listTables API of BigQuery java client, it returns null. But if I use getTable individually, I get the proper data. Is this a known issue, or am I doing something wrong. Following is the code that returns null value for numBytes:

```
Page<Dataset> datasetPage = getAllDatasets("projectId");
        if(datasetPage!=null) {
            for (Dataset dataset : datasetPage.iterateAll()) {
                for(Table table : dataset.list().iterateAll()) {
                    System.out.println(table.getNumBytes());  // Returns Null. **
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question listTables api is designed to return only the partial information. This is mentioned in the code document
https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquery/blob/dfa15e5ca08a3227f015a389c4c08732178a73e7/google-cloud-bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/spi/v2/BigQueryRpc.java#L155

Answer (score 1):

In this Public Issue Tracker [thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/148483976#comment8), it has been discussed that getting `null` value for numBytes and numRows using listTables is the expected behaviour. The BigQuery API considers retrieving numBytes and numRows to be an expensive operation and thus returns `null`. So, the listTables only returns partial information on a table.

As a workaround, use `getTable()` to retrieve the information of the table individually in a loop. I tested the below code snippet and was able to get the table size in bytes for all the tables.

```
public static void getAllTableSize(String projectId) {
    try {
      BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
      Page<Dataset> datasetPage = bigquery.listDatasets(projectId);
        if(datasetPage!=null) {
            for (Dataset datasetTemp : datasetPage.iterateAll()) {
                for(Table table : datasetTemp.list().iterateAll()) {
                    Table tableTemp = bigquery.getTable(table.getTableId());
                    String tableName = tableTemp.getTableId().getTable();
                    Long tableSize = tableTemp.getNumBytes();
                    System.out.println("Table Name: " + tableName + "  " + "Table Size: " + tableSize);  
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (BigQueryException e) {
        System.out.println("Error occurred: " + e.toString());
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes individual getTable returns all the information as i mentioned in the question itself but my main concern was why its not available for listTables @Vishal K

Comment: The reason i am asking this is because call getTable individually for thousands of table is time consuming

Comment: Hi @SachinJanani, please check my updated answer. The same issue as discussed in the Google Issue Tracker. You can also STAR the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).