# Java BigQuery API Table.getNumBytes() is the same as Physical Bytes?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have an application that has a component that consolidates BigQuery table sizes and type of storage. I'm using com.google.cloud.bigquery.Table that extends TableInfo, However, it only has getNumBytes() and getNumLongTermBytes() methods it doesn't have getNumPhysicalBytes(), getNumActiveBytes(), getNumLogicalBytes() methods, probably because I'm using an older version of the package.

I want to verify, in this version, is getNumBytes() considered as Active Bytes? and is it also considered as Physical Bytes or Logical Bytes?

Thank you!

**edit:** I'm using this version of the package

[image]

Comment: Might be total storage for the table ( I didnt see logical bytes in the version [2.23.2](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-bigquery/2.23.2/com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableInfo#com_google_cloud_bigquery_TableInfo_getNumBytes__) page.) Since this is an older version, it is possible that logical/physical bytes billing model has not yet been implemented for this version. The latest version 2.34.2 has getNumActiveLogicalBytes() and getNumActivePhysicalBytes()

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned in this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69972170/19378826), It appears that getnumbytes will produce  null results due to the cost of this operation. Would recommended to upgrade to latest version(stated to the comment) get the specific table values.

Comment: Hi Nester, I think that's not true. The table instance will only return null values for some particular methods, including getnumbytes() if it came from client.ListTables where each instance in the returning list will have table instance with partial information. But in this case, if you call the client.getTable directly, it will give you full information including getnumbytes().

as for the recommendation, of course the concern will be resolved by upgrading to the latest version. However, the question is about a specific version.

Thanks for commenting btw.